# Swift: download image from Internet and cache them doesn't work properly. need suggestions

Tags: swift, caching, uicollectionview, alamofire

I am new to swift, and I am building an App that download images from the Internet and display in a UICollectionView, I can achieve this function successfully, however, it seems like overtime you scroll the screen, it downloaded the images again and again, which may causes a lot of data of the users. I found that I can use cache to solve this problem, but it didn't work, I think I did everything right, but seems the data didn't stored in the cache. here is the code, anyone can help me solve this? thanks

```
var imageCache = [String: UIImage]()
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").responseJSON { (response) in
        if let jsonFile = response.result.value {

            var arrayOfPosts = [Posts]()

            for post in jsonFile as! NSArray {

                let postObj = Posts()
                postObj.postThumbnailUrlString = post.valueForKeyPath("featured_image_thumbnail_url") as! String

                arrayOfPosts.append(postObj)
            }


            let imageUrlString: String = arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row].postThumbnailUrlString

            let imageUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: imageUrlString)!







            if let imageFromCache = imageCache[imageUrlString] {

                cell.imageView.image = imageFromCache
                return
            }

            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

                imageCache[imageUrlString] = imageToCache

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {



                    cell.imageView.image = imageToCache
                })

            }

            dataTask.resume()



        }

    }


   return cell

}}
```

I also have a class of Posts and a customized collectionviewcell. this stocked me a long time, really hope anyone can help me solve this problem. thanks!!

Comment: Use `SDWebImage` library to download image, it will caching image also.

Comment: If you're already using Alamofire, it might be better to consider [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage). They have, much like SDWebImage, a `UIImageView` extension that does asynchronous image retrieval, and it solves a number of problems in the code you included above. (For example, not only does it cache, but it handles if the cell is reused for different index path, etc.) You can replace all of the above image retrieval and caching code with the `cell.imageView.af_setImageWithURL` method.

Comment: I tried before as you said since I already use Alamofire, but I don't know why it does the same job as the code above. do I need to create a cache to store the data or Alamofire created it automatically? thanks, I am pretty new to swift~~

Comment: Actually I tried AlamofireImage, Haneke, and other similar library, they all can download the images sucessufully, but they all same, each time I scroll the collectionview, the image will change quickly to the right one, which I think is because it didn't cache the image. I don't know why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

**Swift 2.2 or 2.3**

Add --> pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.5' in your pod file.

**Swift 3.1**

Add --> pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3' in your pod file.

Put the following line in your code which will automatically cache the image and download it as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     //hit your web service here to get all url's
 }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return arrImageURL.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{ 
   cell.imgViewPhoto.af_setImageWithURL(arrImageURL[indexPath.row], placeholderImage: UIImage())
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but I didnt put placeholderimage, do I have to specify placeholderimage or ".at_setImageWithURL (NSURL (string: "abc.com")) already stored the cache? Cause it didnt work in my case. Thanks

Comment: cell.imgViewPhoto.af_setImageWithURL (NSURL (string: "abc.com"))
its already maintain cache,there is no need for placegholder image..!

Comment: But it didnt work for me. Everytime I scroll the screen, the image quickly change to the right one, which means it download it again. I don't know why?

Comment: Don't hit your web service in cellForItemAtIndexPath
,see edited answer

Comment: I see. Let me try this. Thank you so much.

Comment: The other reason I hit the web service in cellForItemAtIndexPath is beacuse I  want to implement a collectionview inside a tableview, can I have a problem to assign the data from the JSON to the collectionview, thats why I did it inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath. Do you have any experience about configure collectionview inside tableviewcell? I found the datasource and delegate quite confusing. Thanks

Comment: I tried your suggestions, problem solved, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Kingfisher is a lightweight and pure Swift implemented library for downloading and caching image from the web. This project is heavily inspired by the popular SDWebImage. And it provides you a chance to use pure Swift alternative in your next app.
[kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Comment: Do you know if kingfisher can append the image to cell without loading again? Because if i'm on the 30th cell and I scroll back to the 1st, then it loads them again, from memory but still if the phone is old its annoying