# Alamofire .dowload takes a lot memory (ios, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i downloaded images from the server with alamofire framework. I worked with Alamofire.download . Each image has size above 1MB +-, but after each request memory increase a lot. After downloading 4 images the memory used is above 171MB and after that each image give more than 35MB.
Downloading code is:

```
Alamofire.download(mainReguest, to: self.destination)
        .downloadProgress{ progress in
          self.progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
        }

        .response{ response in
            if response.error == nil, let imagePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
                self.addNewImageToTheScrollView(img: image)
            }
    }
}
```

Code with destination is:

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                               in: .userDomainMask,
                                                               with: [DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions.removePreviousFile])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889134/swift-download-image-from-internet-and-cache-them-doesnt-work-properly-need-s/38890731#38890731

Comment: Try this link and let me know if you have any confusion..!!

Comment: What are the dimensions of downloaded images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this...

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
```

Specifically with the fact that you are (presumably) downloading a compressed format of your image.

However, `UIImage` is uncompressed in memory. So each pixel of your image will take 4 bytes of information (red, green, blue, alpha).

So if you have an image that is (for example) 5 mega pixels.

Then 5,000,000 pixels * 4b = 20MB.

So, I imagine your images are around 10MP?

The best way around this is to optimise your image download. If you're displaying an image on an iPhone then there is no point downloading a 10MP version of it. You might as well resize it to be much much smaller.

Ideally, you should be resizing the images on the backend before the download happens.

Comment: yap, it was a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Alamofire's code is ok. Most likely you have issues somewhere in UI part, for example because of the high image resolution. The first thing you have to do is to localise an issue. To check networking code please comment all UI related code and run your app one more time.

```
Alamofire.download(mainReguest, to: self.destination)
    .downloadProgress{ progress in
//      self.progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }

    .response{ response in
        if response.error == nil, let imagePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
            print("Image is successfully downloaded!")
            //self.addNewImageToTheScrollView(img: image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was in UI part

Comment: func addNewImageToTheScrollView(img: UIImage?) {
        if let imageResponse = img {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageResponse.crop(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: imageResponse.size.height/2, width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: 140)))

            self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)

Comment: here is the code which increase memory self.contentView.addSubview(imageView) and i don't understant what to do whith this

Comment: @sergs like I said, get the backend to resize the images to be much much smaller. Then download the smaller version.